Looking for animated film with a child who sees their father killed with a morning star
I've been scratching my head with this one for a few days now. I remember an animated movie which I watched sometime as a child (so it's at least 7-8 years old probably more). Here are the scenes I somewhat remember:
Early in the movie some guy (I think he was the father to the main character or something) gets struck down by a man with a morning star or ball and chain/flail.
I believe there was a giant somewhere who might have been picking his teeth with a sword (although that might have been another movie).
So not a lot to go on, the only thing I really remember is the scene with the guy who gets killed with the morning star thingy. I would be really impressed and grateful if someone manages to pull a movie out of this mess.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), describe the characters and the style of animation, was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points.  The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

I think it's Quest for Camelot, which was released in 1998. The scene happens a little differently than I remember it, but here is the video of it on YouTube.
I recognize the evil knight's face from my memories of this scene. I refused to watch the rest of the movie and made my mom take me home from the theater.

I don't know why you got downvoted; it seems you were right. And I can confirm the "giant using a sword as a toothpick" scene is present.

This is totally the movie I meant although the scene is a bit different than i remember, but it has been a decade or so....
Thank you so much, this has been one of those movies that floats around in your memories for so long and just taunts your inability to recollect its exact details ;)

Probably Black Cauldron or Fantasia if it's Disney (I can't see anything else likely to contain it) but era of animation would help a lot if you could manage a guess. Could be the animated Lord Of The Rings (I know the live action one has Sauron and the Nazgul leader with a mace and morningstar but no idea about animated one). Everything else I can find that might be relevant is either obscure or Japanese and I haven't seen them so can't comment without just listing a hundred possibilities.
